# How to increase the memory of the TFS TEAMCITY process

Tags: tfs, teamcity

We are running Teamcity connected to TFS. On our Teamcity server there are two Java processes one for running Teamcity and one for connecting to TFS. The Teamcity process, I am able to increase the amount of RAM associated with it by updating the following environment variable TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS.

The other process for connecting to TFS, I am not able to increase the RAM. I was able to retrieve the command line for this process and noticed there was only 1gb of memory allocated to it. As can be seen by the following command line.

```
 C:\TeamCity\jre\bin\java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base- 
 directory=C:\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\plugins\tfs\tfsSdk\14.119.2\native -Xmx1024M
```

The real issue is the second Java process is taking up 100% CPU and  hopefully by increasing the memory for this process it will alleviate the issue.

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be hosting TeamCity on the same infrastructure as your on-prem TFS.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the Question. Teamcity and TFS are on separate servers, the issue is in the Java Connector running on the Teamcity server connecting to TFS.